# How to modify the values of x, y and z in the parameter Ellipsoid

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

We encounter some problems when using the untiy3d engine.
How to modify the values of x, y and z in the parameter Ellipsoid by code when using the Ellipsoid Particle Emitter in the program?

PS: We use the version: 3.5.0 and the Ellipsoid Particle Emitter of the Legacy Particles with iOS target platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this thread on Unity Answers site:

- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14200/script-access-to-ellipsoid-property-on-emitter.html